# How to give form field default value if the value is not set in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I want to make add and update action in same view, therefore, I need to check if the data is exists, for example:

```
@if (0 !== count($data))
    {{ $data->value }}
@end if
```

And I found a new way to do that

`{{ $data->value or '' }}`

In form situation

```
@if (0 !== count($data))
    {{ Form::text('name', $data->value) }}
@else
    {{ Form::text('name', '') }}
@endif
```

or

```
{{ Form::text('name', isset($data->value) ? $data->value : '') }}
```

This is not work

```
{{ Form::text('name', ($data->value or '')) }}
```

I want to find out more Laravel way to do something like above.

Answer (score 0):

Make a html Macro instead :)

```
Form::macro('textfield', function($default = "")
{
    return '<input type="text" value="'.$default.'">';
});
```

[Laravel Macros](http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros)